# Merge two directories keeping larger files

Tags: bash, file, merge, directory, find

Consider for example

```
mkdir dir1
mkdir dir2

cd dir1
echo "This file contains something" > a
touch b
echo "This file contains something" > c
echo "This file contains something" > d
touch e

cd ../dir2
touch a
echo "This file contains something" > b
echo "This file contains something" > c
echo "This file contains more data than the other file that has the same name but is in the other directory.  BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla. bla!" > d
```

I would like to merge `dir1` and `dir2`. If two files have the same name, then only the one which size is the largest must be kept. Here is the expected content of the merged directory

```
a # Comes from `dir1`
b # Comes from `dir2`
c # Comes from either `dir1` or `dir2`
d # Comes from `dir2`
e # Comes from `dir1`(is empty)
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt? Is the directories recursive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that no file name a newline:

```
find . -type f -printf '%s %p\n' \
  | sort -nr \
  | while read -r size file; do
    if ! [ -e "dest/${file#./*/}" ]; then
      cp "$file" "dest/${file#./*/}";
    fi;
   done
```

The output of `find` is a list of "filesize path":

```
221 ./dir1/a
1002 ./dir1/b
11 ./dir2/a
```

Then we sort the list numeric:

```
1002 ./dir1/b
221 ./dir1/a
11 ./dir2/a
```

And fianlly we reach the `while read -r size filename` loop, where each file is copied over to the destination `dest/${file#./*/}` if they don't already exists.

`${file#./*/}` expands to the value of the parameter `file` with the leading directory removed:

`./abc/def/foo/bar.txt` -> `def/foo/bar.txt`, which means you might need to create the directory `def/foo` in the `dest` directory:

```
  | while read -r size file; do
    dest=dest/${file#./*/}
    destdir=${dest%/*}
    [ -e "$dest" ] && continue
    [ -e "$destdir" ] || mkdir -p -- "$destdir"
    cp -- "$file" "$dest"
   done
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on the other answer due to not enough reputation, but I was getting a syntax error due to missing `fi`. I also got an error where the target directory needed to be created before copying. So:

```
find . -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -nr | while read -r size file; do if ! [ -e "dest/${file#./*/}" ]; then mkdir -p "$(dirname "dest/${file#./*/}")" && cp "$file" "dest/${file#./*/}"; fi; done
```